# What's the best way to have different parent field initialization?

Tags: java, design-patterns, design-principles

I have a class as below

```
public abstract class MyObjectManager {
   private final Map<MyKey, MyObject> objects;
   private final MySystem system;
   MyObjectManager(MySystem inputSystem) {
     system = inputSystem;
     // also initialize the "objects" field.
   } 
   public void write(MyKey myKey, MyObject myObject) {...}
   public MyObject read(MyKey myKey) {...}
   public abstract MyObject getNewestObject();
}
```

I need two types of ConcreteManagers which will have different map implementation, for example,

One uses `new LinkedHashMap(CAPACITY_1, LOAD_FACTOR_1, true){ // override the removeEldestEntry(){// logic 1}}`.

The other uses `new LinkedHashMap(CAPACITY_2, LOAD_FACTOR_2, false){ // override the removeEldestEntry(){// logic 2}}`.

I don't want to pass the map as a @param since the map implementation is fixed for each ConcreteManager.

Should I use a strategy pattern or factory pattern to have different map initialization?

Or should I move the `objects` field to each implementation classes? But their implementation of `read and write` methods duplicate a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, it seems to me that you could add the map as a parameter the abstract class, then pass the concrete map instance in the children constructor. For example:

```
public abstract class MyObjectManager {

    private final Map<MyKey, MyObject> objects;
    private final MySystem system;

    MyObjectManager(final Map<MyKey, MyObject> objects, MySystem inputSystem) {
        this.objects = objects;
        this.system = inputSystem;
    }
}

public class ConcreteManager extends MyObjectManager {
    public ConcreteManager(MySystem inputSystem) {
        super(new LinkedHashMap(CAPACITY_1, LOAD_FACTOR_1, true), inputSystem);
    }
}
```

This way fulfils your constraints:

- The Map class is fixed to a concrete manager implementation
- The objects attribute remains in the parent class

Comment: Good answer, but it'd be a better answer if you kept the original `MySystem` parameter, to show how it is still a parameter to the subclass constructors, and simply passed along to the base class.

Comment: The original constructor was *package-private*, so you should keep that too. There is actually no reason to ever make a constructor of an abstract class `public`, because it can only ever be called from subclasses, so `protected` or *package-private* is more appropriate. The subclass constructor can of course be `public`.

Comment: Excellent Andreas, thank you for your observations. I updated the example.